# BASH tail logfile and send mail on matched condition

Tags: bash, email

Completely clueless with Bash, but trying to learn to accomplish this single task.

I need a script that can tail the last 50 lines of a logfile, looking for the string "ERROR", and send an email if that condition is true.

I can do bits and pieces manually, but am not able to build something that works completely to stick in a cron. Sendmail works by itself.

```
tail -n 50 /var/log/unifi-video/recording.log | grep ERROR
```

works to at least output that. Ideally I'd like an email only if ERROR is found in the last 50 lines, else no action needs to be taken. If anyone can assist with the if/else statement to make this happen, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to do this in a one liner you could use something like:

```
[ $(tail -n 50 /var/log/unifi-video/recording.log | grep ERROR | wc -l) -gt 0 ] && yourmailcommand
```

This just pipes the output of your `grep` to `wc -l` which returns how many lines are returned from grep. If that count is greater than 0 then it will execute that bit after the double ampersands. If you want to include an `else` in the event that no `ERROR` lines are found you could:

```
[ $(tail -n 50 /var/log/unifi-video/recording.log | grep ERROR | wc -l) -gt 0 ] && yourmailcommand || dosomethingelseinstead
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. I must have just been overthinking it, I was trying to make a function, pipe the result to a string variable, and then email that. The syntax was destroying me. I will play with this solution today and let you know how I made out. Thanks so much!

Comment: Perhaps, as part of your `mail` command or `mutt` or whichever mail command you use as part of this line you could grab your `tail -50 /var/log/unifi-video/recording.log` as the body or attachment. Maybe before this test line you could `tail -50 <yourfile> | last50errfile.txt` then you can use `mutt -a last50errfile.txt <youremail>`, and then after the line `rm last50errfile.txt`. Doesn't have to be too complicated.

Comment: Thanks for that, I deleted the earlier comment as I posted without thinking of the various ways it could be attacked. I had to break down exactly WHY your solution worked, with the && || and I saw why my attempt broke it. Playing in BASH is both fun and frustrating at the same time.

Comment: Yea.. that `&&` and `II` is bash trickery that allows you to short-hand an `if` statement. It's very useful for condensing simple `if` type stuff into a single line. That same statement will work fine as a more traditional `if`, and if you have more than one thing you want to do inside your `then` block, then it's a good idea to expand it out into a formal `if`.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` exits with status 0 if a match is found, 1 if not, so something like

```
 tail -n 50 /var/log/unifi-video/recording.log | grep -q ERROR && <sendmail command here>
```

would do what you want. (The `-q` option suppresses any output, because you don't care what line actually matched, just that a match was found.)